# Is it possible to download files from from file hosting sites using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: qt, network-programming

I tried my level best to download a file from uploading.com but all in vain. I tried every possible way of redirection, but all in vain. It always ends up with error Moved Permanently and if you try redirections it ends up downloading the web page. Huh!

```
This is the cookie which i have to pass to QNetworkAccessManager:

S=gmail=gPwZoKGL8hgGA4ZHoej_Tg; S=gmail=xrWQCf29oq77myB3uSRKPg;

request.setUrl(url);
          request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpPipeliningAllowedAttribute, true);
          cookieJar->setCookiesFromUrl(QNetworkCookie::parseCookies(cookie),url);
          manager.setCookieJar(cookieJar);
          reply=manager.get(request);
```

The finished signal calls the following slot

```
int statusCode=0;
            statusCode=reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
           if(statusCode>300)
           {
               if(statusCode==307||reply->rawHeaderList().contains("Location"))
               {
                url=reply->header(QNetworkRequest::LocationHeader).toString();
                request.setUrl(url);
                request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpPipeliningAllowedAttribute, true);
                cookieJar->setCookiesFromUrl(QNetworkCookie::parseCookies(cookie),url);
                manager.setCookieJar(cookieJar);
                reply=manager.get(request);
                return;
            }
```

The download fails as it downloads the webpage instead of file. The url and cookies are provided by flashgot addon, firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if "uploading.com" does not have their own native API: you are going to need to parse the html from their website and then edit the necessary html as if you were a user on their webpage to download a file.

I need more information about what you've tried and what you would like to do to answer this post. You should check if they have their own API first. It's definitely possible to do this using Qt.

Comment: Could you perhaps put up some sample code that better explains your problem and error messages that you have been receiving?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with cookies. Am i passing the cookies properly!